# Display div based on Group metabox selection

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I am having an issue with the below code when it comes to displaying a div based on a specific metabox is filled in. I am using the Group metabox selection from CMB2 to handle my metaboxes. As of right now when the newblock_url is filled in it is only displaying the div without the href which is the else portion of the code, same goes for when the metabox is empty. I have looked around but have been able to figure out a solution for the if get_post_meta to work with a repeatable group. All of the metabox names are correct and display properly once I remove the if statement.

What am i missing with the if get_post_meta that will correct this issue?

```
 <?php echo '<section class="row cf">';?>
 <?php global $post; $entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'news_group', true ); foreach ( $entries as $key => $entry ) {?>
 <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newblock_url', true) ) : ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $entries [$key]['newblock_url'];?>">
     <article class="col-1 spotlight">
        <?php if ( $entries [$key]['news_image'] ) : ?><img src="<?php echo $entries [$key]['news_image'];?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"/><?php endif; ?>
        <div class="spotlight-content">
            <h5><?php echo $entries [$key]['news_image_title'];?></h5>
            <p><?php echo $entries [$key]['news_image_desc'];?></p>
        </div>
    </article>
</a>
 <?php endif; ?>
  <article class="col-1 spotlight">
 <?php if ( $entries [$key]['news_image'] ) : ?>     
    <img src="<?php echo $entries [$key]['news_image'];?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"/><?php endif; ?>
        <div class="spotlight-content">
            <h5><?php echo $entries [$key]['news_image_title'];?></h5>
            <p><?php echo $entries [$key]['news_image_desc'];?></p>
        </div>
    </article>
 <?php } //endforeach ?>
 <?php echo '</section>';?>
```

Comment: you have enough rep here to know that plugin specific questions are off-topic here :(

Comment: this is not a plugin question @MarkKaplun

Comment: either it is a plugin question or a PHP question, the only wordpress specific code is get_post_meta and you use it correctly

Comment: it's a php question @MarkKaplun My issue has nothing to do with CMB2 but with my PHP code

Comment: Which is why I am confused as to why it is not work with a repeatable group @MarkKaplun

Comment: 1. which makes it off-topic 2. it is probably impossible to answer without knowing what should be in the meta and what is actually there. You probably need to do some value dumps to see if the values you get are what you expect to get

Comment: I don't see how it is off topic but that is your opinion. You could of just not answered at all if my question really bothered you @MarkKaplun but thank you for your input and have a great day!!

Comment: Man, it is time you learned how the site works, comments are not answers, that is why they exist

Comment: Honestly don't you have anything better to do then leave pointless "comments". I thought this website was about helping others in the community not leaving pointless remarks. I see you are not a busy person so I will end this comment as I asked my question accordingly to the rules of the website and labeled it correctly. I am sorry my questions was not up to your standards. You sir enjoy your day!! @MarkKaplun

Comment: if you already have the meta value (as used on the next line) then why are you not just doing `if ($entries[$key]['newblock_url']) :` ..? doesn't seem to be a need to use get_post_meta twice at all

Comment: I think the point that @Mark Kaplun was trying to make was that your question is off-topic since it's either to do with CMB2, a 3rd party plugin, or it's a PHP syntax question, which is also off-topic. Ultimately it's difficult for us to help you here since we have limited information of your project, and may also require intimate knowledge of CMB2. I have posted a suggested answer on a whim, please try it and then perhaps update your question/comment on my answer if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your question what the actual problem is; on a hunch, should it be this:

```
if ( ! empty( $entries[ $key ]['newblock_url'] ) ) :
```

... instead of:

```
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'newblock_url', true ) ) :
```